# Zend Framework and Doctrine 2 - where do you put your entities?

Tags: zend-framework, models, doctrine-orm

I'm using ZF with Doctrine 2 with the Bisna application resource to tie the two together. Up until now I've been putting my entities, proxies, repositories, and service layers in my own App folder under libraries. So, for example, my entities would have a namespace of App\Entity. This has worked OK but it seems strange to not have all my entity stuff under the models directory of the ZF layout.

So, now I'm trying to move everything into the models directory and ZF is not able to find my classes any longer. I made sure to change the proxy and mapping namespaces and directories in my application.ini config to match the new locations and namespaces (I changed my entity namespace to just be Entity and made the same appropriate changes for the repositories and service layer.

In my login controller I call the UserService:

```
$userService = new Service\UserService($em);
```

I get back a fatal error saying the class can't be found. Any idea what I'm missing here?

> Fatal error: Class 'Service\UserService' not found...

The namespace on my UserService class is set to Service. This file is sitting in application/models/Service/UserService.php.

```
namespace Service;

class UserService
{
...
}
```

Here are some pieces from my application.ini showing my directories and namespaces

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace = "Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingNamespace = "Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingDirs[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/Entity"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `Service` namespace location to the autoloader.

Try something like this in your Bootstrap class

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

    require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $serviceAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Service', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($serviceAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Service');

    return $autoloader;
}
```

**Edit:** You probably already had something registering the `App` namespace, just replace that.

Comment: I was loading App using the autoloaderNamespaces[] array in application.ini. I don't think that will work for this. I think I will have to do like you've shown above. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! I had to add a class loader for all three namespaces - Service, Entity, and Repository. It would be nice to have an explanation as to why I needed it for Entity at least. That should have been taken care of through my Doctrine Resource.

Comment: @Jeremy The Doctrine resource only configures an autoloader for the Doctrine namespace